# Unable to access neither accesstoken nor idtoken from iOS Firebase authentication api

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
func signup() {

        provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
            if error != nil {
                
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
            
            if credential != nil {
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        
                    }
                    
                    print(authResult?.credential)
                    print(authResult?.additionalUserInfo?.profile)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As per firebase documentation from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors, one can access idtoken and access token from credential object but unfortunately there are no such properties. So far no one helped from Firebase team, I believe this is an issue for everyone. I wonder how you all solved this issue.

With the help of this token I can perform API requests further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `getIDTokenForcingRefresh(boolean)`

Comment: from Auth.auth() ?@ElTomato

Comment: never mind got it. Thanks!